# Ubuntu SSD not detected as a bootable device

Tags: boot, uefi, 22.04, 22.10

I recently installed ubuntu 22.10 on a SSD to use a secondary OS for my laptop (I usually run it with windows). My intention was to connect the SSD using a USB cable and boot it from BIOS or using advanced restart (shift + reset) but its not showing up as bootable (UEFI) device from any of those places.

If I connect the SSD to my laptop it autodetects the ubuntu installation and boots it as the primary drive (which make no sense for me, since it is not detected as a bootable device when I look into it). I would like to be able to detect the disk from the bios since I will also be using it on my desktop too (I also tried to check if it was detected on my desktop without any luck).

I've checked the ubuntu installation and made sure to have an EFI partition (just to make sure that I didnt install the ubuntu as a Legacy drive (not really sure how this work)). Also tried reinstalling 22.04 and faced the same issue. Does any one have an idea why the ubuntu installation is not display as a bootable device on the BIOS? The pendrive I used to install it, its detected properly btw.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs grub2's boot files into first drive's ESP -- efi system partition, no matter what you select. Old valid bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 If you have ESP on external SSD, change UUDI of mount of ESP in fstab, reboot so that ESP is mounted & reinstall grub. It will then install to external drive's ESP. External drives directly boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi or the drive entry. A grub install to the external drive will also create that entry.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will look into it and try it

Answer (score 2):

Solved it using referring to the link sahred on the comment from my question:
bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

The easiest way to solve the issue is to remove any other disk on your pc and then install ubuntu again, the bootable partition will then be installed on your  first drive (because its the only one), and then it will appear in the BIOS normally and you will be able to select that partition to boot your pc.